# Folding a sheet of paper (Computer Vision)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, linear-algebra

I'm working on a task trying to transform a 2D sketch with folding creases to a full 3D representation. **Red lines will be valleys and Blue mountains/tops**. I would like to calculate the transformed/Mapped coordinates {P1'...P8'}. I Haven't found any good software that could do this automaticly but would appreciate tips.

[image: Folding Pattern]

- **a** - folding angle
- **P** - coordinate
- **E** - element
- blue line - folded mountain
- red line - folded valley

**[Folded](http://i50.tinypic.com/21mx643.png)** With a1 = a2 = a3 = 90 deg (pi/2 rad) (folded angle)
and arrows as surfare normals

I'm using Matlab but I'm looking for general algorithms for solving this problem.

Assuming point **P0** is fixed in origo and element **E1** won't change its coordinates, how should I best describe the transformation? Should I use inhomogeneous or homogeneous coordinates, polar coordinates?

For instance, point P8 depend on the other coordinates which depend on the angles.

I suppose I could use some kind of adjacency matrix for the Points(Nodes) and/or a matrix that pair every element with its Nodes.
E.g: [E1 P0 P4 P5 P1 ; E2 P1 P5 P6 P2 ; ...]

The transformation for every coordinate is transformation+rotation and the transformation depend on the coordinate/element. But it gets tricky with several element connected...

How can I neatly tranform a 2D "paper" with folding patterns to 3D coordinates?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the paper will not run into each other? Also what is the folding order (rotation is NOT commutative)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate through every folding creases, and compute the transformation of all pixels lying on one side of the crease.

you can use a tranformation matrix to compute the coordinates of the folded points. have a look at [the wikipedia article describing transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

first, translate all points so that the crease is aligned with an axis, then rotate all the points on one side of the crease according to the direction of the crease. you can then reverse the first translation so that the figure comes back to its original position. repeat with the process with the next crease, until you have completely folded the figure.

using matlab, matrix computation are pretty easy to preform.

Comment: Sound somwhat what I had in mind! I'm using Rodrigues' rotation formula. However, when the folding pattern gets more complicated I need to sort which points to fold I believe. Folding all other would make a mess? Have a look at this pic. What do you think? [link]http://i49.tinypic.com/2ewfozq.png)

Comment: eck ! what a folding pattern ! for such a pattern, you will have the problem that folding moves other points than the ones you are folding. clearly pushing on the blue line will drag some points along the red lines... and that's much more complicated than what i did describe.

Comment: Ha yes! I see this sort of problem as very advanced. Do you think it is under reasonable circumstances possible to write an algorithm that work for this sort of pattern, but that also for an arbitrary pattern? First day on the job, lucky me hehe...

Comment: The problem was solved recursively by using the technique Adrien described. However, one has to make sure that one element isn't treated more than once, e.g if there are closed loops.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use techniques used to describe robots with multiple rotational joints; than your problem could be described as a [forward kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_kinematics) problem. Another interesting reading could be [this](http://www4.cs.umanitoba.ca/~jacky/Robotics/Papers/spong_kinematics.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to apply a linear transformation to each point on one side of the line.

The transformation is a rotation about an axis, whose transformation matrix is [given by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)

[image]

Since the axis is not centered about the origin, you will need to first apply a translation to the origin, then do the rotation, then translate back.